# Why does a faulty USB port cause Ubuntu 20.20 to boot slowly?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb

A USB port on this system is faulty; I can tell because devices plugged into it don't work and I get dmesg reports like

```
[   11.673418] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 2, error -110
[   22.425445] usb usb2-port1: attempt power cycle
```

The Win10 install on the same machine gives a generic USB failure message relating to the same port. No big deal, there are many others, tape over the port and get on with life. But, Ubuntu pauses for around a minute on boot between starting `systemd-udev` (identifiable for its log messages when booting with `debug` kernel parameter) and mounting the root FS (`dmesg` line `EXT4-fs (sdb3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)`)

So, why the delay, and how can I overcome it so the system comes up promptly again?

Answer (score 0):

After much rummaging, I hit on this solution:

Script `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top/udev` runs early in the initramfs boot stage, prior to mounting the root FS and starting systemd proper. It calls `udevadm settle`, which waits for all hardware change events to complete (unsure what exactly constitutes completion, except evidently my USB port stuck in this half-set-up state didn't count). The timeout for `settle` defaults to 2 minutes, but I guess the kernel had a 1-minute timeout for giving up on USB init.

The solution: edit that script to add `--timeout=10`, then use `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`  to update the initrd. Technically that could cause trouble if my SATA controller took an age to come up as it would probably fail to mount the root FS, but that doesn't seem to happen in practice, and all other hardware *should* work as if hotplugged.